# How to get empty of time 00:00:00 from db and assign to a variable

Tags: php, mysql

I have a field in my table called checkout if the user havent checkout by default it is set as 00:00:00 .Im using an if condition to check if checkout time is equal to ='00:00:00' .im new to php and other answers did not help

Comment: Note: databases use null to denote a value doesn’t exist. It’s usually a better way than using magic values which might happen anyway (what if someone orders at midnight?)

Comment: How to write an sql query. How to process the result set. How to write a conditional statement.  No coding attempt posted.  Too Broad.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen Yes youre right .I used null then it worked

Answer (score 0):

Step you do.

1)Set a column as `DATE in mysql` if don't insert any value it will automatically take "0000-00-00"

2)Then just write the query to get the result

[image]

I hope it will help you.

Answer (score -1):

You have two options.

1. Set checkout field value default = NULL.
2. This is wrong. **equal to ='00:00:00'**.
   To compare the value you have to use == operator not = operator. = operator is assignment operator.